# create index using a where statement sqlite

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I'm using sqlite 3.8 (using .net `System.Data.SQLite` version 1.0.88.0). -edit it looks like the site lies, a query shows its 3.7.17 which should be new enough). Sqlite appears to support [where on indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html). When I do the below I get a syntax error `near "where"`. If I remove the where statement its fine. I'm confused am I not writing it correctly?

```
var a = cn.Query("SELECT sqlite_version()").First(); //3.7.17
var b = cn.Execute("create table if not exists User(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `name`  VARCHAR(63)  NOT NULL, `flags`  TINYINT  NOT NULL , UNIQUE (name));");
var c = cn.Execute("create index ti1 on user(flags) where (flags&1)=1"); //syntax error new where
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using 3.8? Try `SELECT sqlite_version()`.

Comment: @CL.: Looks like the site lies. Its 3.7.17 but that should be new enough as the page says "The newer schema format is used by default in version 3.7.10 and later" -edit- F, it appears 3.7.16 doesn't support it but 3.8 does. Tested by using the shell